# Crash in accessing derived class member after casting to baseclass

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I have following code.

```
class BaseHandler
{
    //Blank class
};
typedef void    (BaseHandler::*InstantFunc)();

class MyDrivedClass: public BaseHandler
{

    //Constructor
    ...
    // Data Members
    ...
    char *m_someMember;
    ...
    void DoJob();
    //More functions
    ...

}
MyDrivedClass::DoJob()
{
    //accessing Work Something with 'm_someMember' data;
}


class ForCallback
{
public:
    ForCallback(BaseHandler* handler, InstantFunc callback);

    BaseHandler* GetHandler();
    InstantFunc         GetCallback();

    void                Handle(SProgressiveInfo info);

protected:
    BaseHandler*     m_handler;
    InstantFunc      m_callback;
};

ForCallback::ForCallback(BaseHandler* handler, InstantFunc callback):
m_handler(handler), m_callback(callback)
{

}

 BaseHandler* ForCallback::GetHandler()
{
    return m_handler;
}

InstantFunc ForCallback::GetCallback()
{
    return m_callback;
}

void ForCallback::Handle()
{
    (m_handler->*(m_callback))();
}

//thread1--
somefunction()
{
    //Creating mydrivedclass.
    MyDrivedClass *drived = new MyDrivedClass();


    ForCallback *cBack = new ForCallback(drived, MyDrivedClass::DoJob);

    //store cback in some global map
    StoreInGlobalMap(cBack);


}


//Thread2---
someotherfunction
{
    //Get cback from the global map

    ForCallback *cBack = GetFromMap();
    cback->Handle();
}
```

When I ran this code in iOS(compile using xcode) it is working fine but when I am running this code on windows(compile using visual studio)I am observing some crash.

On investigating I found in thread2 when we handle the callback, the function 'DoJob' is getting called, the 'this' pointer of 'MyDrivedClass' is invalid and I am not able to access the 'm_someMember'. I am using mutex to synchronize the data between thread and there is no problem of synchronization.

During debugging I found that at the time of creation of the object of 'ForCallback' we are passing the address of 'MyDrivedClass' but address passed to the constructor of 'ForCallback' is different. Which could be due to conversion of derived class to base class pointer

The workaround which I found is to change the definition of the ForCallback to

```
ForCallback::ForCallback(void* handler, InstantFunc callback):
m_handler(()BaseHandler*)handler), m_callback(callback)
{

}
```

But this is still a workaround.

Please someone explain the reason of different behavior on iOS(Xcode compilation) and on Windows(Visual studio 2015 for compilation)
What is the correct solution which will work with both iOS and Windows.

Comment: <<During debugging I found that at the time of creation of the object of 'ForCallback' we are passing the address of 'MyDrivedClass' but address passed to the constructor of 'ForCallback' is different. >> how can that happen ? It is just passing the pointer, address won't be changed.

Comment: Your code does not compile. In fact, it is not even a stripped-down version of any compilable code. Please either make that your example is compiling properly, or use [this one](http://pastebin.com/0mmpfDLJ) instead.

Comment: Base should have a virtual destructor

Answer (score 0):

The address of derived object may be different because it has virtual methods, while the base class has not. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593783/mismatch-of-this-address-when-base-class-is-not-polymorphic-but-derived-is) for clarification. Also, if you use virtual inheritance, then the addresses are different too. Also, if you use multiple inheritance, then address of base class may be different.
When you convert `MyDrivedClass*` to `BaseHandler*` in constructor, compiler is smart enough to change address appropriately.

However, it is not so clear with member function pointer casts. You can read [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/09/70002.aspx) to see how complicated they are. In fact, you cannot simply assign member function pointer of `MyDrivedClass` to that of `BaseHandler`, and MSVC2013 tells you about it:

```
temp.cpp(34) : error C2664: 'ForCallback::ForCallback(const ForCallback &)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'void (__cdecl MyDrivedClass::* )(void)' to 'InstantFunc'
        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

In the other hand, you can force it with `static_cast` or C-style cast. In such case MSVC2013 warns you:

```
temp.cpp(34) : warning C4407: cast between different pointer to member representations, compiler may generate incorrect code
```

I think in such case calling your method for object of type `BaseHandler` is incorrect, because class `BaseHandler` has no such method. So you are calling inexisting method here. I hope someone knowing C++ standard better would comment on it.