# How safe is it to assume that a derived class's pointer is the same as the first base class's pointer?

Tags: c++, inheritance, vtable

Consider this program:

```
struct Base1 { void *x; virtual ~Base1() { } };
struct Base2 { void *x; virtual ~Base2() { } };

struct Derived : Base1, Base2 { };

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    return &d == static_cast<void *>(static_cast<Base1 *>(&d));
}
```

In all my tests on Clang, GCC, and Visual C++, the return value is `1`.

I understand C++ doesn't actually guarantee this.

However, **practically speaking**, is this safe to rely on?
*(Assume no virtual inheritance. **Edit:** I assume polymorphic base classes.)*

What realistic situations are there (if any) in which a pointer to a derived class would need adjustment before it can be used as a pointer to its **first** (non-virtual, polymorphic) base class?

Comment: @user541686 Doesn't apply to the given example, but somewhat related [Mismatch of 'this' address when base class is not polymorphic but derived is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593783/mismatch-of-this-address-when-base-class-is-not-polymorphic-but-derived-is).

Comment: @user541686 That's an interesting question, but one with no clear answer. I could say that, for all I know, this holds true for all MSVC versions up to last week's, but even that tells nothing about the next update since the behavior is not mandated by the standard. Or you could tag it as `compiler-construction` but that may invite answers about hypothetical implementations where all the usual assumptions break down. Just curious, is there a practical context or concern that prompted the question?

Comment: @dxiv: (Thankfully?) the next compiler version can't just break it randomly since then it would break ABI compatibility with existing binaries, and people would become very sad. In any case, it's easy enough to test this in the code with an assertion or something to catch potential future breakages, so I'm not worried about future changes either way. Mainly I'm just asking about the status quo. And yes, it's based on a practical concern—I was trying to "un-templatify" some code and then realized that doing so (in the manner I tried, at least) would rely on this assumption being true.

Comment: @user541686 MSVC is known (and actually [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/portability-at-abi-boundaries-modern-cpp?view=vs-2019)) to break ABIs between versions, though not necessarily the layout basics. Compilers bound to the [Itanium C++ ABI](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#class-types) (including gcc) probably satisfy the assumption, though I haven't read the spec page to the last detail. Even so, this doesn't begin to answer the question in general.

Comment: @dxiv: Right, I realize not *every* ABI is set in stone, but *this* kind of ABI does seem like it would be. It wouldn't just break things interfacing with an old CRT, it would also break all kinds of Windows ABIs (including COM etc.) the world has written code around. The only thing they can really do is to introduce a "new" type of class or inheritance mechanism that keeps the old one intact. Which I mean is theoretically possible but... honestly I'm not worried. In fact the whole vtable layout might as well be set in stone now, due to the C interface code in Windows headers.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a reason why the compiler (or the linker, if `-flto` is used) might theoretically shuffle the order of the base classes in a class.  It might consider this an optimisation opportunity, if `Base2` is used more than `Base1`.

I don't think this is in any way likely, but it is possible.